# jQuery UI Draggable with revert:true and droppable with greedy:true

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

So I need to have a droppable inside another droppable, both of which can accept the same type of draggables.

I made the two droppables and set the inner one to greedy and it works beautifully...for the first drag/drop.  After dropping into the inner droppable I try to drag into the outer droppable, the "over" event is not fired, however, when dropped the drop event fires.

Take a look at this fiddle to illustrate the issue.  You will notice that after dropping in the inner element the outer element's over event is no longer fired (no log in the console).

http://jsfiddle.net/J7azG/52/

Comment: I guess I don't see the issue. I don't see your code doing anything on the "over" even for any of the droppables. What isn't working?

Comment: Sorry, the console.log didn't get saved in the fiddle, I updated the link.  The only solution I have found is to completely re-init the outer droppable after dropping in the inner droppable like this: http://jsfiddle.net/J7azG/53/

Comment: When I try the fiddle on Chrome the "Over" console log successfully runs every time even after a drop on the inside.

Comment: For me, also in Chrome, after dropping on the inside the 'Over' console log does not work again until I drag into and out of the inner div again.  It seems like the revert does not reset the state of the over on the outer element or something.

Comment: See it in action here: http://www.screenr.com/Kth8

Answer (score 1):

Bless you rosswil. For me it wasn't triggering the hoverClass I set. I traced it to the "over" method not being triggered. I've been fighting with this bug for hours and the solution you posted ( jsfiddle.net/J7azG/53) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this can help :

change `revert:true` to `revert:'invalid'`

> See this fiddle for code to result

http://jsfiddle.net/penjepitkertasku/J7azG/134/

```
$(".block").draggable({
    revert: 'invalid'
});
```